# javascript oop, instanceof and base class

Tags: javascript, oop, polymorphism

I am designing some class hierarchy in JavaScript. It works fine so far, but I can't see how to determine if an object is an "instance" of a parent class. Example:

```
function BaseObject(name){
    this.name = name;

    this.sayWhoAmI = function(){
        console.log(this.name + ' is a Derivation1 : ' + (this instanceof Derivation1));
        console.log(this.name + ' is a Derivation2 : ' + (this instanceof Derivation2));
        console.log(this.name + ' is a BaseObject : ' + (this instanceof BaseObject));
    };
}
function Derivation1(){
    BaseObject.apply(this, ['first derivation']);
}
function Derivation2(){
    BaseObject.apply(this, ['second derivation']);
}

var first = new Derivation1();
var second = new Derivation2();
```

`first.sayWhoAmI();` logs this:

```
first derivation is a Derivation1 : true
first derivation is a Derivation2 : false
first derivation is a BaseObject : false
```

while `second.sayWhoAmI();` logs this :

```
second derivation is a Derivation1 : false
second derivation is a Derivation2 : true
second derivation is a BaseObject : false
```

I feel like both `first` and `second` object should have say that they are instances of `BaseObject`.

I understand that JavaScript may not be made for this, but I wonder if there's a way to achieve that.

Comment: Only calling `Base.apply(...)` does not setup inheritance. You have to set the prototype properly. See: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/wJE6s/. Also have a look at this question for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145700/javascript-inheritance-instanceof-not-working?rq=1

Comment: Felix you should write this as answer, that's exactly what I need and your fiddle demonstrate it simply. Don't let someone else steal your reputation!

Comment: Agreed he should add an answer, but he's probably not worried about boosting his rep by .01%!

Comment: It was very late and I was too tired to provide a full answer, sorry. Added one now, I hope it's understandable. Don't hesitate to comment if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only calling `Base.apply(...)` does not setup inheritance. All that `.apply` does is setting `this` to the first argument, nothing else. It is important to call the parent constructor, but it is not sufficient.

What you have to do is setting up the prototype chain properly.  That is, you have to set `Derivation1.prototype` to something that inherits from `Base.prototype`.

Since each instance of a constructor function inherits from the constructor functions's prototype, you will see code such as

```
Derivation1.prototype = new Base();
```

This is **a bad idea** and you can already see why: `Base` expects arguments to set up instance specific properties (`name` in this case). But we don't care about these properties, since we are initialising them later in the child constructor with `Base.apply(this, ...)`.

So all we need is an object inheriting from `Base.prototype` and luckily, ECMASCript 5 defines a function which can do that for us ([polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create/#Polyfill)):

```
 Derivation1.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
```

This creates a new object inheriting from `Base.prototype`. Now, since you replaced the original prototype with a new object, you have to set the `constructor` property so that it points correctly to `Derivation1`:

```
Derivation1.prototype.constructor = Derivation1;
```

Below is a complete example. Also have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/wJE6s)  and [this excellent answer by T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072556/objects-dont-inherit-prototyped-functions/11072626), which explains basically the same issues, but maybe in a better way.

---

**Example**:

```
function BaseObject(name){
    this.name = name;
}

// move properties shared by all instances to the prototype!
BaseObject.prototype.sayWhoAmI = function() {
    console.log(this.name + ' is a Derivation1 : ' + (this instanceof Derivation1));
    console.log(this.name + ' is a Derivation2 : ' + (this instanceof Derivation2));
    console.log(this.name + ' is a BaseObject : ' + (this instanceof BaseObject));
};

function Derivation1(){
    BaseObject.apply(this, ['first derivation']);
}

Derivation1.prototype = Object.create(BaseObject.prototype);
Derivation1.prototype.constructor = Derivation1;

// some useless method of the child "class"
Derivation1.prototype.someOtherMethod = function() {
    return 42;
};

var first = new Derivation1();
first.sayWhoAmI();
```

​