# Why is it necessary to use Object.create()

Tags: javascript, oop, object, inheritance, prototype

Here is my code:

```
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;

  if (price < 0) throw RangeError('Invalid');
  return this;
}

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'food';
}
Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
var cheese = new Food('feta', 5);
```

When I check the variable in my console, I see the following:

`Food {name: "feta", price: 5, category: "food"}`

Which is what I had expected.

However, if I omit `Object.create(Product.prototype)` I see the same results because of `Product.call`.

That said, **what would be best practice in this case?** Is `Object.create(Product.prototype)` even necessary for inheritance and if so, why?

Comment: [This is a good explanation of what's going on.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661078/javascript-oop-instanceof-and-base-class/11669057#11669057)

Comment: See also [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196). You don't see any difference because you didn't add anything to `Product.prototype`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
Product.call(this, name, price);
```

gives the same effect as

```
this.name = name; //argument name from the function constructor
this.price = price; //likewise, argument of function constructor
```

but it does nothing to set the prototype property of the Food object.  With this line

```
Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
```

it ensures if a property of the Food object is looked up and JavaScript cannot find, it will follow the *prototype chain* to Product.prototype

Let's elaborate your example

```
function Product(name, price) {
   this.name = name;
   this.price = price;

   if (price < 0) throw RangeError('Invalid');
      return this;
}
```

and add a function to calculate the tax

```
Product.prototype.calculateTax = function() {
    return this.price * 0.1;
}
```

Now with this line

```
Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
```

the following will calculate the tax correctly

```
var cheese = new Food('feta', 5);
console.log(cheese.calculateTax());
```

Omitting that line

```
//Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
```

it will gives the error *TypeError: Object # has no method 'calculateTax'*

Comment: Thank you Khnle, this answer was very succinct.